# Models not appearing if inherited from Azure Document type

Tags: swagger

My models don't appear in the Swagger UI if I inherit from Document (Azure DocumentDB) as follows:

public class EmployeeDocument : Document
{ ... }

The Model/Model Schema appears in the Swagger UI just fine if I remove the inheritance... anyone have any idea how I can correct this?

VS2015/Swashbuckle/Web Api App

Tx

Answer (score 1):

Please derive from [Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.aspx), which is the base class of Document. The [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.document.aspx) class extends from DynamicObject, which might be handled differently by code-generation tools like Swagger.

Comment: Note that in this case you will need to cast a document to dynamic to get results as Resources:

Comment: Isn't just the opposite? Document derives from Resource, so it's a subclass of it? I think this is the weakes point in CosmosDB documentation, there's nowhere to learn wich are the types returned by the api, and how to deal with them if we don't want to cast the projection into concrete classes... What if I need the projection as an ExpandoObject?

Comment: You're right - fixed it as Base class. Thanks for the feedback on the docs - we're happy to address it. Can you please contact us at AskCosmosDB@Microsoft.com for a dialog on what is missing there?